# Publish Blackberry app for BB10 and BBOS

Tags: blackberry, publish, blackberry-10

I want to publish an app for BlackBerry 10 but already have a version on the App World for the BBOS. Will the version that if targeted for BB10 overwrite the old version that was targeted for BBOS? How do I upload the BB10 version but keep both versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you upload an application, you have to choose the OS target for a specific release. It won't overwrite your current version if you select only QNX targets (BB10 and/or PlayBook). You can select a custom set of devices/OS version for each release.

Comment: Question though, If i have a release for all BB10 models and I want to update Q10 and Q5 only, would that work that way? Will Z10 keep getting the old one?

Comment: Yes, you can choose to make a release available only for specific devices (even for specific CPU across a same device). But the NDK provides way to package the same app for the Q10/Q5 and the Z10, you should take advantage of that and release only one package for all BB10 devices.

Comment: Well so far I released the same for all, but I don't want Z10 to update if I make changes for Q5 and Q10 only. Some people hate downloads